# xrdp - auto join session

Tags: raspberry-pi, skip, autologin, xrdp

I have an `xrdp` setup on my raspberry `pi`.

**XRDP:**

[image: XRDP]

I only have one session in the list (**PI**).
Is it possible to skip this screen and go directly to the remote control after connecting?

Thanks

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? Apparently the autorun value in xrdp.ini is the way to go, but I haven't had much luck.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone dealing with this, I'd try saving the configuration on your RDP client. For Windows RDP go to "Options" on the bottom left, and then under "General" enter your specifications. In this case, leave the username and password blank and make sure to save it. From then on those credentials will be used to auto login.

For other clients like Royal TS, right-click on the connection and open the "Properties" dialog. Going to "Credentials" located on the left navigation bar will allow you to save any log in configurations you want to use.

I've never tried this without a username and password, so if it doesn't work with blank configurations, I'd consider setting up a username and password if you want to bypass this page.